# »Einen Klick entfernt«, aber fürs Tippen?

Tags: single-word-request

Wie man weiß, bedient man Touchscreens mit *Tippen*, nicht mit *Klicken*.

Dadurch wäre der Ausdruck *etwas ist nur einen Klick entfernt*  im Kontext von mobilen Geräten mit Touchscreens unpassend. Auf Englisch lässt sich das elegant mit *only one tap away* ausdrücken... und auf Deutsch?

Comment: Beim "Tippen" denke ich eher an den Druck einer Taste auf der Tastatur. Im Fall von Touch-Screens würde ich eher vom *Berühren* sprechen. Für den Vorgang, bei dem durch eine Berührung eine Aktion ausgelöst wird (etwa das Navigieren zu einer neuen Internet-Seite), finde ich auch auf Touchscreens das *Klicken* als passend.

Comment: Danke für deine Meinung! Ich bin gespannt, ob andere es auch so sehen; wenn ja, bleibe ich beim "Klick".

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Es kommt auf den Kontext an. Mein Smartphone hat keine Tastatur (abgesehen von der Bildschirmtastatur), also ist "Tippen" eindeutig und verständlich und imho auch gängig. "Berühren" klingt für mich dagegen merkwüdig. Hab ich auch noch nie gehört, mit Ausnahme, wenn jemand versucht hat mit "Hand drüber halten" das Gerät zu bedienen und dann jemand sagte: "Ne, du musst das Ding schon berühren.".

Comment: "Nur einen *Schritt* entfernt." - bin aber unentschlossen, ob mir der Vorschlag selber gefällt, deshalb als Kommentar.

Comment: @Stephie Ist nicht schlecht. Dennoch habe ich meine Zweifel. Ein *Schritt* kann etwas sein, was mehrere "taps" benötigt, z.B. das Ausfüllen eines Formulars könnte man auch als *Schritt* bezeichnen.

Comment: Ich hätte tendenziell "abtippen" verwendet - allerdings hat das natürlich das gleiche Problem, nämlich das Fehlen eines "richtigen" Substantivs

Comment: Die für mich gängigen Worte sind, klick(en), wisch(en), swipe(en) und drücken.

Comment: Vielleicht „nur ein Fingertipp entfernt“?

Comment: @YannickIhmels Guter Vorschlag! Klingt ein kleinwenig nach "Werbesprech", gefällt mir aber trotzdem.

Comment: @Stephie Das soll auch Werbesprache sein. Richtig erkannt, Yannick! Kannst du den Kommentar als Antwort re-posten? Dann werde ich es akzeptieren.

Comment: @Em1: Ich finde "tippen" in diesem Kontext auch sehr merkwürdig ... "antippen", ja, das bezieht sich auf Touchscreens. Aber "tippen"? Das geht nur mit einer Tastatur beziehungsweise physischen Tasten.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Oder mit den Fingern... Ich tippe ja auch jemandem auf die Schulter. Brauche dafür keine Tastatur. – Das ist hier auf GL die zweite oder dritte Frage, wo es um das Thema geht und ich hab einzig und alleine hier auf GL jemals gehört, dass die Leute "tippen" unnatürlich finden. Im täglichen Sprachgebrauch höre ich nur "tippen", daher kann ich nicht nachvollziehen, wieso das hier überhaupt diskutiert wird. HubertSchölnast kommt aus Österreich, ich war daher der Annahme, das ist Österreichisch.

Comment: @Em1: Das kann durchaus regional sein; ich bin aus Südwestdeutschland, und für mich impliziert "ich tippe auf dem Smartphone" mindestens, dass gerade die Software-Tastatur benutzt wird, da es ansonsten "ich tippe auf dem Smartphone Schaltflächen an" heißen müsste. Vielleicht ist "tippen" in anderen Gegenden durchaus verbreiteter.

Comment: _Druck_ wie in _Tastendruck_? Oder _Anschlag_ ;) Hm, _Moment_, _Berührung_, _Schritt_, _Sekunde_, _Aktion_, _Hauch_, _Wimpernschlag_, _Wisch_, _Fingerzeig_ können ggf. auch funktionieren

Comment: Einen Datscherer entfernt x3 (Ja, ich mag keine Wischphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also ich würde mich am ehesten an die Antwort von @YannickIhmels halten:

> nur ein Fingertipp entfernt

Ist zwar Werbesprache - was bereits festgestellt wurde. Aber hab dies in dieser Form schon öfters auf Webseiten, die für Mobile Geräte optimiert waren, gesehen.